# count all objects within a values_list Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is a follow up question to this

[Django object has no attribute in a _set.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649320/django-object-has-no-attribute-in-a-set-filter?noredirect=1#comment130056735_73649320)

```
    @property
    def mathe2(self):
        return self.lehrertabelle_set.count()
    @property
    def mathe3(self):
        return self.lehrertabelle_set.values_list('Stundenanteil_bei_WE', flat=True)[0] + self.mathe2
```

I got so far that I can calculate that but I need everything within values_list counted together, pls tell me how, I have no clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sum() to sum values in the list

```
 @property
def mathe3(self):
    return sum(self.lehrertabelle_set.values_list('Stundenanteil_bei_WE', flat=True)) + self.mathe2
```